# Can python subprocess pipe reattach to original child process when program restart?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, reconnect

I am looking for a safe way to restart my python program that is able to regain control of the child process launched before restart.

I use subprocess with thread to monitor the `stdout`/`stderr` of a long run `command` which will continuously generate some output message.

The sample code snippet is as follow:

```
class PS(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, command):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.command = command

    def run(self):
        try:
            process = subprocess.Popen(self.command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
                ''' do something to line'''
```

When my python main program is terminated (kill its pid for example), its child process (the `command` executed by the `PS` class) is still alive as a background process.

My question is, is there any way in python to "reattach" the child process so that I can keep monitoring its `stdout`/`stderr`?

P.S. I only need it in linux environment, more specifically in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The child will probably die if it tries to write to its standard output after the parent exits, because its standard output was a pipe whose other end was the parent, not a file.

Comment: @chepner I don't know how but I am sure the child process is alive.

Comment: But is it still producing output? Even if it's buffered somehow, you program could still lose some output depending on how long it takes to reconnect. Just write to a file, and have the parent read from the file rather than a pipe.

Comment: I tried a small example (`"while :; do echo $i; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done"`), and that child did *not* survive the parent Python process exiting.

Comment: @chepner the following example `import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'while True: print("test")'])` *does* survive the parent python process exiting.

Comment: Without `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, its standard output is simply inherited from the parent, not set to a pipe whose other endpoint goes away when the parent exits.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, the child process does exit with piping.

Comment: @chepner The `command` I run is actually the QEMU process that starts a virtual machine. I notice that VM is alive after python code terminated. Anyway, as you suggested, just write to file seems a promising solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the standard output of the child is tied to a pipe, the child will receive a SIGPIPE signal if it tries to write to that pipe after the parent dies, since the remote end of the pipe no longer exists.

To ensure the child survives the parent, and to allow the parent to resume, you should simply write to a file and have the parent read from that file instead.